# How can I highlight a sentence that is spread over more than one tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i have text some thing like below..

```
var str="Hi, How are you";
```

If i want to highlight this text in the below HTML in a single attempt rather than spliting it into an array. In document if my HTML is like below..

```
<div> Hi, <span>How are</span> you</div>
```

Please help me on this..I want to search the sentence in document and want to add highlighted effect to it.

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight"?

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight?"

Comment: What do you mean by *highlight*? You can use CSS to style and set background to some color to highlight. Your question is still unclear

Comment: What do you mean by "sentence"? ... No, just kidding. What do you mean by "highlight"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all the sentences are wrapped in a `div` you can try this.

```
$('div').filter(function(){
   return $.trim($(this).text()).toLowerCase() === "hi, how are you";
}).addClass('highlight');
```

Define the highlight class in your css and give an appropriate background color.

Comment: Nice example, never used `filter()`, good to see how it works and what it can do.  One of the good thing about jQuery is there's like 10 different ways to accomplished any given task with it so people get accustomed to using there own way they learned and don't realize there might be a function made just for that to make your life easier... :)  If I had to code that I'd probably of used `.each()` and then compare the text and add the class.  Don't really know how much of an advantage or performance gain `filter()` would have over using `each()` in this case though.

Comment: When you want to filter any set of matched elements based on any condition it is the right thing to use instead of writing a each loop and creating a new set. I think performance wise we are definitely not gaining much.

Comment: Yeah; I'll have to go read up more about `filter()` because right now to me it pretty much just looks like its a slimmed down each method somewhat, all you have to do is change `.filter` to `.each`, `return` to an `if` statement and change from calling `.addClass` outside the function to inside and use `$(this).addClass`.  Seems the only thing filter allows to do is to use chained method calling which could have its benefits and I'm just not seeing them right now.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing to highlight it currently?

You can always set the font css of the div tag

If you just want to GET the text you can do `$("div").text();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").css("background-color","Red");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/KhNCV/7/

or were you asking this

```
$("div").find("span").css("background-color","Red");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/KhNCV/8/